# Mongoose find all and update some

Tags: javascript, express, mongoose

I am using node-cron to run a function every x ammount of time. In the function I want to retrieve all documents from the db and the after some conditions are met i want to change a single field in each document that meets the condition and then save/update all documents in my db.

My approach so far :

```
const Appointment = require("../models/Appointment");
const {
  getDate,
  getMinutes,
  getHours,
  getYear,
  getMonth,
  addMonths,
} = require("date-fns");

const retrieveAllAppointmentsCron = async () => {
  const date = new Date();
  const year = getYear(date);
  const month = getMonth(date) + 1;
  const day = getDate(date);
  const hour = getHours(date);
  const minutes = getMinutes(date);
  if (month < 10) month = "0" + month;
  if (day < 10) day = "0" + day;
  if (hour < 10) hour = "0" + hour;
  if (minutes < 10) minutes = "0" + minutes;

  const nowFormDate = new Date(`${year}-${month}-${day}T${hour}:${minutes}`);
  const res = await Appointment.find()
    .select("-shopId -customerName -service -comments -email ")
    .exec();
    let cancleCounter=0;
  res.map((app) => {
    var appFormEndDate = new Date(`${app.date}T${app.endTime}`);
    if(nowFormDate>appFormEndDate)
    {
        app.active = false;
        cancleCounter++;
    }
  });
  await res.save()
  console.log(`a total of ${cancleCounter} appointments where updated to completed`)
  cancleCounter=0;
};

module.exports = {
  retrieveAllAppointmentsCron,
};
```

The problem here is that find() returns an array of mongoose documents so .save() is not a function.
What is a good practise to do this ? Can anyone explain the logic to me ?
Thanks in advance :)

p.s dont mention my time formating I know it is horrible and I will replace it with ISO dates in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to save the whole array, you might want to save each document individually. To do so, you'll have to make it wait all these possible promisses with `Promise.all` probably.

```js
// ...
  let cancleCounter=0;
  await Promise.all(res.map(async (app) => { // <-- wait for all to solve.
    var appFormEndDate = new Date(`${app.date}T${app.endTime}`);
    if(nowFormDate>appFormEndDate)
    {
        app.active = false;
        await app.save(); // <-- save only 1 document!
        cancleCounter++;
    }
  }));
  // await res.save() <-- removed
  console.log(`a total of ${cancleCounter} appointments where updated to completed`)
  cancleCounter=0;
// ...
```

Comment: This worked like a charme on the first try ! Thanks a lot ! So from my understanding (because i tried this approach as well) was that although this was an async func and I used await before saving each itteration returned a promise which was not handled ? So i needed Promise.all to handle them ?

Comment: We just needed to make sure the `.save()` is used in each document and not in the array.
But since we need to also update a number to show how many we did, we used the `Promise.all()` to make sure it only does so at the end.